# Using django and scrapy together

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have two crawlers in Scrapy that scrap some data from website and then finally store in database `(sqlite3)`. Now I want to use Django for admin. The Django has to manage crawlers i.e. activate, deactivate, delete etc. Similarly the data from database is to be listed in admin of Django. And all the crawlers are to be run from Django. Upto now, I have learned how to use custom command in Django but I am not being able to figure out the rest part. Can any one help me with idea? My code is simple tutorials from documentations. I have followed the link

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/
```

Can anyone help me with idea? It would be a great help. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are really two ways to manage those crawlers, synchronously or asynchronously.

synchronously means that the user or the management command is doing something like whats done in [scrapy crawl command](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/commands/crawl.py), this approach has three drawbacks:

1. spiders are usually taking a long time to do their jobs, not an amount of time you want a web user to wait with an open session to the server, on the other hand, it should be okay if its launched from a django management command.
2. you'll have to follow carefully the way spider are activated using python code, this will be more complicated than simply run `spider crawl ....`
3. scrapy is using twisted library, a software architecture very different than django's, while mixing them is possible, if feel a little awkward sometimes.

asynchronously means you let the launcher (i.e. user or django management command) go and have him polling django database for answers or reported progress, the main drawback here is the communication between the launched spider and the waiting user, reporting the user about the progress as well as dealing with errors i.e the crawled site is down or changed its structure etc.

bottom line, both options are possible, I prefer the asynchronous way, keep scrapy boxed (consider even using scrapyd) and have the user polling (ajax) for the spider progress.

Comment: Thank you @Guy. That was very helpful. I may bother you more :-)